# i want the iframe to show only if

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have an iframe, which I have embedded onto a production site. I am still working on it [here is the iframe the table with results](http://www.chessbook.net/ZULUTESTINGSITE/index.php?option=com_chess&id=350)

The problem is that I don't want any one to see it, So i am wondering is there any way to add something to the link look's like.

```
http://www.chessbook.net/ZULUTESTINGSITE/index.php?option=com_chess&id=350**&result**
```

That way only when i add the &result it'll show the iframe
below is the `iframe` code on the page

```
<div>
   <iframe src="http://users.hellzoneinc.com/eric258/preview.php" width="50%" 
           height="300" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" name="results"> 
   </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea but we would need to see the PHP code that is building the page to be able to be totally sure

Comment: Of course you could just **give it a go** and answer your own question!

Comment: the thing is i dont know how to inser t a file on this forum... i tried to add the  <?php if(isset($_GET['result']) but the site dont open anymore

Comment: Just paste the code and then highlight it all and press CTRL+K

Comment: I'm confused as to why you want to use an iframe for this. If you are using PHP why not echo the result on form submission?

Answer (score 1):

you should do something like below:

```
 <?php if(isset($_GET['result']) OR $_GET['result'])=='Your_SOME_VALUE'){?>
<div>
<iframe src="http://users.hellzoneinc.com/eric258/preview.php" width="50%" height="300" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" name="results"> </iframe>
</iframe>
        </div>
 <?php }?>
```

And your URL should be

```
http://www.chessbook.net/ZULUTESTINGSITE/index.php?option=com_chess&id=350&result=Your_SOME_VALUE
```

Comment: u can upload ur php script on ur server and give me the link

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested method should work quite nicely **assuming that the script containing this HTML is a .php script** and will be passed to the PHP interpreter. If the extension of this file is anything other than `.php` then of course the PHP script part will not be passed to the interpreter.

All you need to do is this

```
<?php
if ( isset($_GET['result']) ) :
?>
    <div>
       <iframe src="http://users.hellzoneinc.com/eric258/preview.php" width="50%" 
               height="300" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" name="results"> 
       </iframe>
    </div>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

As normal accesses will not have this new `&result` parameter set in the `$_GET` array, this iframe should only be placed in the page when you add the extra parameter to the url

Note: All you need to test for is the existance of the `&result` parameter that you are adding to the original URL as you are not adding any value to it i.e. you are not doing `$result="something"`

If your HTML is in a file called `something.html` then of course you could just make a copy of it and call it `something_test.html` and then you dont have to bother with the parameter or the PHP script addition.